# Which solution is the closes to type-specific implementation of generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

C++ has a feature I'd like to use in C#, namely type-specific implementation for generic class. What I mean is that I can define a generic class, but provide an exception for specific generic type.

I'm writing a text comparison tool. I've already implemented comparing two files by lines and now I want to implement comparing them by characters. The algorithm is exactly the same - except the compared type. In the first case I'm doing a safe-hashing of text lines into `int`s (safe-hashing in terms that different lines *always* have different hashes), in the second case I'd like to use `char`s.

The naïve solution is to cast chars to ints, but in the worst case it will quadruple amount of memory needed to keep all entries. I could simply hold objects, but applying == to them might cause boxing, which will result in significant performance drops. So I turned to generics.

```cs
public class ComparisonContext<TData> where TData : struct
{
    public TData[] DataA { get; }
    public TData[] DataB { get; }
}

// (...)

if (context.DataA[x].Equals(context.DataB[y])) ...
```

I'm unsure though if it still won't cause boxing. One solution I thought about is requiring that `TData` implements `IEquatable<TData>`.

```cs
public class ComparisonContext<TData> where TData : struct, IEquatable<TData>
{
    public TData[] DataA { get; }
    public TData[] DataB { get; }
}

// (...)

if (((IEquatable<TData>)context.DataA[x]).Equals(context.DataB[y])) ...
```

The best solution would be simply to implement a comparison method inside the context class, specific to `char` and `int` types. But in C# this is not possible.

Is there any better solution in terms of performance and readability than what I came up with?

Comment: Are you sure using `==` on two structs of the same type would cause boxing?

Comment: "requiring that TData implements IEquatable<TData>." is pretty much the correct solution. There is no boxing done as the system knows when you compile it that the generic type is actually a struct.

Comment: @MohsenEsmailpour I honestly haven't checked, but the first "Equals" is actually an `object.Equals(object other)`, so I'm pretty certain it will cause boxing.

Comment: You're wrong, the compiler will select `Equals(T)` if it's defined.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to compare chars and ints?

Comment: Don't concern yourself with memory or performance issues until you have one. C# is pretty efficient these days. When you discover you have a problem then fix it. Don't invent problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to implement a comparison method inside the context class, specific to `char` and `int` types. But in C# this is not possible.

If I understand correctly, you just want extension methods on `ComparisonContext<int>` and `ComparisonContext<char>`?

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static bool DataAreEqual(this ComparisonContext<int> context, int dataAIndex, int dataBIndex)
        => context.DataA[dataAIndex] == context.DataB[dataBIndex];
    public static bool DataAreEqual(this ComparisonContext<char> context, int dataAIndex, int dataBIndex)
        => context.DataA[dataAIndex] == context.DataB[dataBIndex];
}
```

Usage:

```
context.DataAreEqual(x, y);
// instead of
// ((IEquatable<TData>)context.DataA[x]).Equals(context.DataB[y])
```

---

Boxing does indeed occur in your first approach, if the `context` that you are using is a `ComparisonContext<TData>`. Since `TData` is only constrained to value types, so calling `Equals` on that will call `Equals(object)`. If `context` is actually a `ComparisonContext<int>`, where the type argument is a type that has their own `Equals` that takes their own type, then there is no boxing.

Boxing also occurs in your second approach, but that's only because you casted to `IEquatable<T>`, which is unnecessary.

No boxing occurs if you wrote `where TData : struct, IEquatable<TData>` and just did:

```
context.DataA[x].Equals(context.DataB[y])
```

If you are on .NET 7+, you can also constrain `TData` to `IEqualityOperators<TData, TData, bool>`.Then you can just compare them directly with `==`, which I think is a bit more readable. This also does not box.

Comment: _"Boxing does indeed occur in your first approach"_ and _"No boxing occurs if you just do"_. Aren't these two the same?

Comment: @shingo Ah, I was thinking that `TData: IEquatable<TData>` in my head, but didn't realise that what I wrote is not clear.

Comment: No, boxing doesn't occur in the first approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7vY7lL

Comment: @shingo only if `context` is `ComparisonContext<NotATypeParameter>` though, which I think is obvious enough...

Comment: @shingo Okay, I think I made it clearer now.